# NHibernate data access without freezing GUI

Tags: .net, winforms, nhibernate, user-interface

I am working with a Windows Forms application which uses NHibernate as an ORM. Our usual pattern looks something like:

1. Get object graph from database and populate GUI
2. Let user edit data in GUI
3. Save object graph back to database

This notion of unit-of-work requires the NHibernate session to live as long as it takes for the user to edit the data and hit the Save button. Hence, our session is instantiated as part of step 1 and disposed as part of step 3.

Now, I want to display an indeterminate progress bar animation during the save operation. Hence, the session cannot live on the GUI thread, as that would cause the animation to freeze if saving takes time.

How can I best solve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to spin off a background worker:

```
BackgroundWorker _worker;

void OnSaveButtonClicked(...)
{
    // Update your entities with the data entered by the user, e.g.:
    _settings.UserName = textBoxUserName.Text

    _worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    _worker.WorkerCompleted += (s, e) => { /* Saving completed,
                                              hide progress bar */ };
    _worker.DoWork += (s, e) =>
    {
        _session.SaveOrUpdate(_settings);
    };

    // Show progress bar:
    // progressBar.Show...    

    _worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

Comment: But that means that the SaveOrUpdate method is called from a thread pool thread, not the thread on which the session was instantiated, doesn't it?

Comment: @TormodFjeldskår: Right. Is that a problem?

Comment: Yes, that is a problem. From the documentation: "The ISession is not threadsafe! Never access the same ISession in two concurrent threads. An ISession is usually only a single unit-of-work!" Ref: http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#transactions-threads

Comment: @TormodFjeldskår: You are misinterpreting this, but it is written in a way that makes it easy interpret it wrongly. It should read like "Never access the same ISession concurrently from two threads". In the code I gave you, you access the session always in only one of the two threads. Please also see this: http://nhprof.com/Learn/Alerts/CrossThreadSessionUsage, especially these parts: "There are valid scenarios for cross thread session usage (background loading with careful sync, multi request spanning session)" and (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) "If you are using the session across multiple threads intentionally and are certain that you are **correctly serializing access to it**, then you can safely ignore this alert.". And that's exactly what we are doing: We are *correctly serializing access to it*, by only accessing it from one thread at a time.